# Determining the path to the the local SQL Server CE database using Data Source

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I've set up the database using these instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546200.aspx) from MSDN site. Which includes first creating the database and then adding that to the project.

Then in data source when opening the database, I've used something like "Data Source=|Applicatoin Data| + filename.sdf" but when using this, I would launch the app then load some data onto it but then i couldn't see the data in the local database I created outside of my project (as explained in the tutorial I linked to) That would only work if i hardcoded to the .sdf file that was created when I first created the database.

I can't seem to find any information on how to make this a relative path where in between builds the data would stay in the database.

Comment: is that a clickone app or winform?

Comment: @giammin It is a windows form app

Comment: Please show us your code for opening the database. Showing us "something like" the code is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the solution your db is copied to the bin directory

when you debug you use that copy not the one on your project.

This is by design. And it is right.

you should do something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    public static readonly string ConnectionString =
        string.Format(@"Data Source=..\..\DbTest\{0}; password='{1}'", DbFileName, DbPassword);
#else
    public static readonly string ConnectionString =
        string.Format(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\{0}; password='{1}'", DbFileName, DbPassword);
#endif
```

Remeber to use 2 different dbs:

one for testing
one for release app with no data

Comment: Yeah i think so but it doesn't persist through the next build, so I lose all the data I put into it

Comment: @TolgaE you should handle the connection string as in my example

Comment: Thanks, it's working now, it does persist through builds. I just had to add an additional ..\ to move up another directory since "DbTest" is another project than my executable

Comment: Also kinda unrelated question (i'm fairly new to .NET) where would you store constants like this?

Comment: @TolgaE i usually create a class named Constants with all const,readonly properties in my business/domain  library or if they are some kind of configuration constant i put them in an xml or .config file